# How to extract a Win32 Cabinet Self-Extractor without executing the extracted file then

Tags: analysis, malware, cab, self-extracting

For a coursework, I have to analyse a malware.

It is a .EXE Win32 Cabinet Self-extractor file. (that's how windows see it, it actually start with 4D 5A 00 03 Hex).
When run, it extract all the files in a folder created, run the malware (batch/VBS files) which at the end delete the folder with the malware files.

I was wondering how is it possible to extract witout executing the malware?
I used ProcDump32 but it gives me: "Process is not 32bits or can't be loaded or is already finished !".

Somehow, I succeed to stucked ProcDump32 and get the folder for few second and copied it before it "disapear" so I got the files, but I'm not sure I gathered all of them and I would like to do it in a proper way.

So I'm looking for an application which can extract the content of a Win32 Cab Self-Extractor file without executing the output files and, if possible, giving the list of extracted files.

Comment: If you just want to do this to analyze the contents, try [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). It can extract files from a `.CAB` file without executing them.

Comment: I tried 7zip and it worked: It extracted without running the malware. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `/?` on the Self-extractor file, it should show `/X:path` or `/T:path /C` to extract the content (according to microsoft kb [262841](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262841) and [197147](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197147))

Comment: The `/?` does not show the help screen, but `<sfx-file> /x:<destination-path>` works for me (don´t know what `/c` is for). You can also use the `/q` switch to extract files without showing any user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use /T:full path of folder /C. Without /C the exe file will be executed.

MySelfExtractingFile.exe /T:C:¥MySelfExtractingFile /C